# change excel cell color with ActiveSheet Object

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Active Sheet object of excel to loop through rows and columns.

I need to change the background color of a cell but getting Application defined or object- defined error on this line

```
ws.Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```

This is the code I am using

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws


For rw = 7 To ws.Rows.Count

   For col = 2 To 12

    'Check the first column and if null then exit

    If ws.Cells(rw, 2) = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

   'Check if article code is less than eight digits
    If Len(ws.Cells(rw, 4)) < 8 Then
        ws.Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        ws.Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If


  Next col

Next rw

End With
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Add `ws.` before that line and see if you still get that error?

Comment: I am anyway saying ws.Cells(10, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0.So where exactly do you want me to add the ws.

Comment: I dont see it in `Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0`

Comment: Just edited the code.It was just something that I was trying

Comment: I just tested the code and it works.

Comment: Strange I am using the exact code and it seems not to be happy.Is that something to do with my sheet then?

Comment: Quick question. Why do you have this loop `For col = 2 To 12` when you are not using the variable `col`? Are you sure the code that you posted above is correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15335/discussion-between-user1131926-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Chats bocked at my work place.Trying to log using my phone

Comment: Wait... is the worksheet protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. You are getting that error because your worksheet is protected. You need to unprotect the sheet and then change the cell colors. When you have finished changing the colors, you can then reprotect it. See this code.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Mypassword As String

    '~~> Change password here
    Mypassword = "Blah Blah"

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Unprotect sheet
        .Unprotect Mypassword
        For rw = 7 To .Rows.Count
            For col = 2 To 12
                'Check the first column and if null then exit
                If .Cells(rw, 2).Value = "" Then Exit Sub

                'Check if article code is less than eight digits
                If Len(.Cells(rw, 4)) < 8 Then
                    .Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    .Cells(rw, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
            Next col
        Next rw
        '~~> Reprotect sheet
        .Protect Mypassword
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I did unprotect sheet from the file menu because it was the columns that were protected and not the file itself and my original code works.Thanks for your help with this Siddharth.